# Perform git add from another directory

Tags: git, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to automatically add my modified files to the staged area in git.

The batch file is situated in my dev/tools directory takes the directory of the git repo as it's first argument.

This is my code at the moment:

```
@echo OFF

IF "%1"=="" (
    echo No directory supplied...
    goto :exit
) ELSE (
    echo Adding all modified files to staged area for %1
    git add %1
)

:exit
```

However, when I'm in the dev/tools directory and run `./test.bat ../temp` I get the following output:

> Adding all modified files to staged area for ../temp
>
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

**How can I perform 'git add .' on a repo situated in a directory that I'm not currently inside using a batch command?**

Comment: Try to `cd %1` before running `git add %1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `cd %1` first before you execute git add

Comment: Works, but how do I get back to the original directory after that?

Comment: If you need to go back to original directory, first do `pushd %1`, then `popd %1`. Manual page for pushd/popd available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771180.aspx

Comment: That's only for windows 8 isn't it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with `pushd %1` could you post some example code please?

Comment: Nope I needed `pushd "%1"`